# How should I plan for a VP win as Nurgle?

Tags: chaos-in-the-old-world

I played a game of Chaos in the Old world today and I came close to winning as Nurgle, whilst trying to win via ticks on my counter. The thing is, I only came close to winning via VPs, and my ticks were fairly bad. I also nearly won via VPs in another game as the Horned Rat.

Considering I seem to be doing something right to win that way (and I got some fairly solid advice about winning via ticks), how can I finish it off and assert my victory point victory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nurgle's general best winning strategy seems to be to go for VPs, not ticks. Khorne goes for ticks, and the other 3 go for either or depending. (This is actually suggested in the rules, near the end in a 2-page spread about strategy.)

In short: dominate all you can partake in every ruination. Those provide the big points.

Comment: Short but correct. By design, Nurgle has a very hard time winning on ticks; he wants them solely to upgrade his chances of VP win.